# Xamarin Android Location updates not being called

Tags: android, xamarin, android-location

I am trying to log location during an activity however I am not getting location updates. I have played around with the min refresh interval as well as the distance interval however it still doesn't work. I followed Xamarin's example for location updates but I've been banging my head against the wall as to why location updates arent working!

```
public class ActivityManager : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationListener, ISensorEventListener
{
    private readonly LocationManager _locationManager;
    private readonly SensorManager _sensorManager;

    private readonly List<Location> _locationCache;
    private readonly List<SensorEvent> _sensorCache;

    private bool Continous { get; set; }

    public ActivityManager(LocationManager locationManager, SensorManager sensorManager)
    {
        _locationManager = locationManager;
        _sensorManager = sensorManager;

        _locationCache = new List<Location>();
        _sensorCache = new List<SensorEvent>();

        Continous = false;
    }

    public void StartTrackingLocation()
    {
        const string provider = LocationManager.GpsProvider;

        if (_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(provider))
        {
            _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    public void StartTrackingAccelerometer()
    {
        var mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("sensorThread");
        mHandlerThread.Start();
        var handler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.Looper);
        _sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Accelerometer),
            SensorDelay.Normal, handler);
    }

    public void StopTrackingLocation()
    {
        _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
    }

    public void StopTrackingAccelerometer()
    {
        _sensorManager.UnregisterListener(this);
    }

    public void StartContinousTracking()
    {
        _locationCache.Clear();
        _sensorCache.Clear();

        Continous = true;
    }

    public void StopContinousTracking()
    {
        _locationCache.Clear();
        _sensorCache.Clear();

        Continous = false;
    }

    public void ExportLocationData(string path)
    {
        var kml = new Kml
        {
            Feature = new Placemark
            {
                Geometry = new LineString
                {
                    Coordinates = new CoordinateCollection(_locationCache.Select(l => new Vector {Latitude = l.Latitude, Longitude = l.Longitude}))
                }
            }
        };

        var kmlFile = KmlFile.Create(kml, true);

        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            kmlFile.Save(stream);
        }
    }

    public void ExportSensorData(string path)
    {
        var csv = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(path));

        csv.WriteField("AccX");
        csv.WriteField("AccY");
        csv.WriteField("AccZ");
        csv.NextRecord();

        foreach (var s in _sensorCache.ToList())
        {
            csv.WriteField(s.Values[0]);
            csv.WriteField(s.Values[1]);
            csv.WriteField(s.Values[2]);
            csv.NextRecord();
        }

        csv.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        _locationCache.Add(location);
        if (!Continous) _locationCache.RemoveAll(l => location.Time - l.Time > 120000);
    }

    public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
    {
        _sensorCache.Add(e);
        if (!Continous) _sensorCache.RemoveAll(s => e.Timestamp - s.Timestamp > 120000000000);
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) { }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) { }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras) { }

    public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, SensorStatus accuracy) { }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was working but very intermittently. The issue appeared to be that another thread that was running was asynchronously to log the sensor data was queueing up operations which were effectively drowning out the location updates.

Removing the sensor data logging started to allow location updates to come through. This seemed strange to me as this seemed to occur despite the sensor data logging being contained in their own thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation I have used for the Android element of a Xamarin.Forms app:

*The communicating class*

```
public class PlatformLocation : ILocation
{
    private readonly global::Android.Locations.LocationManager _locationManager;
    private readonly string[] _providers;
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<PfgLocationInfo> _tcs;

    public PlatformLocation()
    {
        _locationManager = (global::Android.Locations.LocationManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
        _providers = _locationManager.GetProviders(false).Where(s => s != global::Android.Locations.LocationManager.PassiveProvider).ToArray();
        _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PfgLocationInfo>();
    }

    #region Private Methods

    Task<PfgLocationInfo> StartUpdatingLocation(int timeout = 0)
    {

        var lastKnownGpsLocation = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation("gps");
        if (lastKnownGpsLocation != null)
        {
            var pfgLocation = new PfgLocationInfo()
            { 
                Longitude = lastKnownGpsLocation.Longitude,
                Latitude = lastKnownGpsLocation.Latitude,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                Success = true,
                Status = PfgLocationStatus.Valid
            }; 
            _tcs.TrySetResult(pfgLocation);
            return _tcs.Task;
        }

        var lastKnownNetworkLocation = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation("network");
        if (lastKnownNetworkLocation != null)
        {
            var pfgLocation = new PfgLocationInfo()
            { 
                Longitude = lastKnownNetworkLocation.Longitude,
                Latitude = lastKnownNetworkLocation.Latitude,
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                Success = true,
                Status = PfgLocationStatus.Valid
            }; 
            _tcs.TrySetResult(pfgLocation);
            return _tcs.Task;
        }

        LocationListener listener = null;
        listener = new LocationListener(
            _providers.Where(_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled),
            () =>
            {
                if (listener.Task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(listener);       
                }
            },
            timeout
        );

        try
        {
            var looper = Looper.MyLooper() ?? Looper.MainLooper;
            var enabled = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < _providers.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(_providers[i]))
                {
                    enabled++;
                }

                _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_providers[i], 0, 0, listener, looper);
            }

            if (enabled == 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < _providers.Length; ++i)
                {
                    _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(listener);
                }
                _tcs.TrySetResult(new PfgLocationInfo{ Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Status = PfgLocationStatus.Restricted, Success = false });
                return _tcs.Task;
            }

        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException tcex)
        {
            _tcs.TrySetResult(new PfgLocationInfo{ Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Status = PfgLocationStatus.Restricted, Success = false });
            return _tcs.Task;
        }
        catch (SecurityException)
        {
            _tcs.TrySetResult(new PfgLocationInfo{ Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Status = PfgLocationStatus.Restricted, Success = false });
            return _tcs.Task;
        }
        return listener.Task;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ILocation implementation

    public Task<PfgLocationInfo> GetLocationAsync()
    {
        return StartUpdatingLocation();
    }

    public Task<PfgLocationInfo> GetLocationAsync(int timeout)
    {
        return StartUpdatingLocation(timeout);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

*The ILocationListener implementation:*

```
public class LocationListener : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationListener
{
    private readonly HashSet<string> _activeProviders;
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<PfgLocationInfo> _completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<PfgLocationInfo>();
    private readonly Action _finishedCallback;
    private readonly Timer _timer;
    private readonly int _timeout;
    private readonly object _locationLock = new object();

    public Task<PfgLocationInfo> Task
    {
        get
        { 
            return _completionSource.Task;
        }
    }

    public LocationListener(IEnumerable<string> providers, Action finishedCallback, int timeout = -1)
    {
        _activeProviders = new HashSet<string>(providers);
        _finishedCallback = finishedCallback;
        if (timeout > 0)
        {
            _timeout = timeout;
            _timer = new Timer(TimesUp, null, _timeout * 1000, 0);
        }
    }

    #region Timeout Methods

    void TimesUp(object state)
    {
        lock (_locationLock)
        {
            if (_completionSource.TrySetCanceled() && _finishedCallback != null)
            {
                _finishedCallback();
            }
        }
        _timer.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region ILocationListener implementation

    public void OnLocationChanged(global::Android.Locations.Location location)
    {
        if (location != null)
        {
            Finish(location);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
        lock (_activeProviders)
        {
            if (_activeProviders.Remove(provider) && _activeProviders.Count == 0)
            {
                _completionSource.TrySetResult(new PfgLocationInfo{ Timestamp = DateTime.Now, Status = PfgLocationStatus.Restricted, Success = false });
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
        lock (_activeProviders)
            _activeProviders.Add(provider);
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, global::Android.OS.Bundle extras)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case Availability.Available:
                OnProviderEnabled(provider);
                break;

            case Availability.OutOfService:
                OnProviderDisabled(provider);
                break;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    void Finish(global::Android.Locations.Location location)
    {

        var pfgLocationInfo = new PfgLocationInfo()
        { 
            Longitude = location.Longitude,
            Latitude = location.Latitude,
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
            Success = true,
            Status = PfgLocationStatus.Valid
        };
        _completionSource.TrySetResult(pfgLocationInfo);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

***The PfgLocationInfo is just a simple class for holding the results***

This works exactly as required and should be relatively easy to transform to your requirements.

Comment: This isn't really what I was looking for. I have already stated that other samples I have did not seem to work. A dump of some of your code is not really a suitable answer.